# Grouping systemd services

Tags: systemd

I've written about half a dozen `.service` files for the different parts that make up the system I'm working on.  It's useful to be able to start the whole system piecemeal but I'd also like to have a single unit that starts the whole system in one call to `systemctl`.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want a [target-type unit](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.target.html), with all the service units listed as `Wants=` dependencies. Then you start it using `systemctl start unitname.target`. (Make sure not to use `systemctl isolate` here; that will shut down everything except what's in your services' dependency tree, which you presumably don't want.)

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the `WantedBy` key in the `[Install]` section and note an already-existing target. For example, if you want your services to always start up before other users can log in, use `multi-user.target`.

Comment: Yes, the target type with `Wants=` listing all the services seems sufficitient for *starting*, however I can't seem to find any way to make *stop* and *restart* work using a target type.  Is there a type that allows that?

Comment: Magnus, did you ever find a good solution for this?

Comment: Sam, no, I didn't :(

Comment: Sam, Magnus: It looks like stopping the wanted services from a `.target` can be done using `StopWhenUnneeded=yes` in each of the `.service` files.
http://superuser.com/questions/470153/how-to-stop-a-group-of-systemd-custom-services

Comment: In my particular case I can make use of the systemd tools handling globbing :) So, for starting I use a `.target` and for stopping I use `systemctl stop foo.\*` (since all the services involved have service files starting wit `foo.`).

Comment: Setting `PartOf=some.target` on service unit will make it restart when restarting the target

Answer (score 15):

Have you tried using [`PartOf`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#PartOf=) on the sub-units of the target group in addition to `Wants` in the target? Ex: `PartOf=foo.target` in `foo-sub1.service` and `Wants=foo-sub1.service foo-sub2.service` in `foo.target`. I just tried this and was able to start and stop all my sub-units just by starting and stopping the target.

> PartOf=
>
> Configures dependencies similar to Requires=, but limited to stopping and restarting of units. When systemd stops or restarts the units listed here, the action is propagated to this unit. Note that this is a one-way dependency — changes to this unit do not affect the listed units.
>
> When PartOf=b.service is used on a.service, this dependency will show as ConsistsOf=a.service in property listing of b.service. ConsistsOf= dependency cannot be specified directly.

Comment: This provides the other half of the answer give by Tom Hunt--the ability to stop an entire group of services.