# How do I reload a group of systemd services?

Tags: systemd

I want to *reload* (not restart!) a group of services upon an event.

For example, if I update my SSL certificates, I want every service that uses them reloaded (`nginx` and `postfix` come to mind). Neither I want to remember which services on a given server use SSL certificates. It should be enough to have them grouped when they were configured.

On the other hand, I'd like to avoid changing `.service` files provided with the packages, because this will require manual intervention during updates.

How do I accomplish that?

There is an option to [stop a group of services on request](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228277/grouping-systemd-services), but this would make them inaccessible for a second or two, or worse - they may stay down until fixed. I can't afford that.

Comment: I'm not sure how you deploy certs, but here is also a pre-hook and post-hook for most automagic renewals

`/opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto renew --pre-hook "service nginx stop; service postfix stop; service squid stop" --post-hook "service nginx start; service postfix start; service squid start"`

also:
certmonger has postsave and presave commands

Comment: @JacobEvans That's what I use! Earlier there was a problem in a config file parser for certbot: it didn't permit semicolons. Therefore you had to use a command line argument, or do it in one go. Right now all this is unnecessarily.

Comment: if you make your `.service` file edits as *overrides* you can avoid the updating problem.  `sudo systemctl edit foo.service` will store your changes in `/etc/systemd/system/foo.service.d/override.conf` rather than alter the installed `foo.service` file.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Create `/etc/systemd/system/ssl-reload.target` with the following contents.

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Services which need reloaded with SSL certs are updated.
PropagatesReloadTo=nginx postfix
```

Then create another file: `/etc/systemd/system/ssl-reload.path`

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Restart services which use SSL when the cert directory changes

[Path]
PathChanged=/path/to/your/ssl/certs/dir

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then:

```bash
systemctl enable ssl-reload.path
systemctl start ssl-reload.path
```

With that said, after changing something in your SSL directory, the desired services should be reloaded automatically.

if you don't want the automatic behavior, then don't use the `.path` file, and just issue `systemctl reload ssl-reload.target` manually after you change SSL files.

Comment: This doesn't work as described with two problems. `1` A "path" unit *activates* an associated unit, which defaults to a "service" with the same basename. `2` *Activation* is not a "reload", but a "start" action. To actually make this work, you need another `ssl-reload.service` that calls `systemctl reload ssl-reload.target`, or the target doesn't get reloaded at all.