# How to start other systemd services in a specific sequence starting one service?

Tags: systemd

I want to create a systemd service that when started will start a specific sequence of other services and when stopped will stop the sequence of services, something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=master process
After=graphical.target

[Service]
ExecStart=test1.service, test2.service, test3.service, test4.service, test5.service
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=255
Type=notify

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
Alias=master_process.Service
```

`test1`, `test2`, `test3`, `test4`, and `test5` are the services that I want to execute in this sequence.

How can I do this?

Comment: Sounds like `PartOf` may be useful; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/228277/117549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a way to give systemd a list and say "start them in this order".  What you should do instead is to indicate for each service where in the order it should start.

So in your `test2.service` you would include `After=test1.service` (or you can do it the other way around and in `test1.service` include `Before=test2.service`), and do the same for each service that needs to start in a certain order, using `Before` or `After` to indicate those dependencies.

Comment: ok, but how can I start all the services using the master service, like:        sudo systemctl master.service, and this starts test1, test2, test3?

Comment: I added partOf and Wants in my script too.